# Fill whole sheet with the same color in Excel - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm looking for a way to set the color of the background of an Excel worksheet using Java's Apache POI

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try XSSFSheet.setTabColor from the [POI Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#setTabColor%28int%29)

Edited:

You may need to apply it to each cell / row style.

[How to apply background color for the rows in excel sheet using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334855/how-to-apply-background-color-for-the-rows-in-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi)

Another similar example/better explanation here:

[excel poi: apply foreground color to blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440119/excel-poi-apply-foreground-color-to-blank-cells?rq=1)

Comment: This function sets the color of the tab's background, but not the sheet's one. Thanks anyway, I'll keep on searching for a solution!

Comment: @biggtor Updated the answer.  Another Resource: http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/set-background-color-and-add-border-to.html  taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242828/starting-with-apache-poi

Answer (score 0):

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: have you tested your code? The use want to set the whole sheet,and you just defined a cell style!